# How to reload the data in data grid view after closing another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm doing a simple program that shows the data for some clients in data grid view, and there is a add new client option. I'm doing that by opening new form just for that. The problem is when the new client is added it wont appear in the data grid in the first form. I've made a "refresh" button and it worked but I want this task to be done automatically by the program. Here is my code so far:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Client> list = new List<Client>();
        list = cnn.Select();
        dataGridClients.DataSource = list;
    }

private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Client> list = new List<Client>();
        list = cnn.Select();
        dataGridClients.DataSource = list;
    }
```

this are the functions I'm using to display the data. And here is the add client form code:

```
private void AddClientFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = dateSelected.Year +"-"+ dateSelected.Month +"-"+ dateSelected.Day;
        string cycLenght = txtBoxInsertCycle.Text;
        int len;
        if(txtBoxInsertName.Text != "" && txtBoxInsertDate.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                len= Convert.ToInt32(cycLenght);
                cnn.Insert(txtBoxInsertName.Text, date, len);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the fields", "Error");
        }
    }
```

this is the add client function it's invoked when the button is clicked. Here is a photo so u can understand better what I'm doing:[image]

So how to do the refresh automatically?

Comment: what is cnn? And you bound the list to the datagrid but you modify cnn!

Comment: cnn is variable from my class DBconnect which is the connection with the data base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create event with delegate.

you can watch : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a way to call refresh when the window closes.

But maybe a leveraging a bindingSource instead of a list is a better way to handle your grid data. This way you aren't trying to keep a local list and a datagrid datasource in sync. The BindingSource is a single authority for the grid/application data.

I created a new winform project. Added a Client class, added it as an object data source with the winform designer open. Then drag/dropped the class onto the form and it created a datagridview with a binding source all wired up.

This is the form code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //var clientBindingSource = new BindingSource(); // Set in designer
            clientBindingSource.Add(new Client {Id = 1, Name = "Rob"});
            clientBindingSource.Add(new Client {Id = 2, Name = "Tim"});

            //clientDataGridView.DataSource = clientBindingSource; // Set in designer
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Updating the binding source updates the grid            
            clientBindingSource.Add(new Client {Id = 3, Name = "Kathy"});
            //clientBindingSource.EndEdit(); // May or may not have to end edit to see results
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not to show the data, but to show the new data when the second form closes. The problem is that the second form is other class and the data grid view and the binding Source are not know in the second form(add client) context

Answer (score 0):

Since you bound `list` to your datagrid. you just have to add the new client to your list. You could just append the following line to your code.

```
list = cnn.Select();
```

under

```
cnn.Insert(txtBoxInsertName.Text, date, len);
```

in your try block. Seems `cnn.select()` just selects all data. U can also write

```
list.add(x);
```

where x is the newly added client. But I don't know how this corresponds with your data base. My first solution is not efficient since you always overwrite most of the memory you already have.

Just add this to your 2nd form

```
List<Client> list;
```

and change the constructor of your 2nd Form

```
public Form2(List<Client> list)
{
 this.list=list;
...
}
```

so the list is present to your 2nd form as well.

Comment: The problem is not to show the data, but to show the new data when the second form closes. The problem is that the second form is other class and the data grid view and the list are not known in the second form(add client) context

Comment: Then just submit the list as the parameter while loading the form (updated my post).